# How to close the existing running program when i created another duplicate of the program?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This is the code:

```
Dim newform As main
        newform = New main()
        newform.Show()
        newform = Nothing
```

`newform.close` or `Me.Close/Me.Exit/Me.Dispose` will close thesame form,
without using close the program will leave many program running

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking. Closing a form will close that form. Closing the startup form will quit the app. Exactly what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run a single instance of your application or you're trying to stop the proliferation of `main` Forms alone.

Comment: i duplicated my main form and each time i click a button it must show the duplicated form what i'm trying to solve is how do i close the old main form? and leave only the duplicated form

Comment: So this is nothing about closing programs and simply about closing forms. The answer to this should be fairly obvious. What do you ALWAYS do with an object that you want to access later? You assign it to a variable. In your code you are explicitly setting the variable to `Nothing` that the form was assigned to. Why? Why not leave the form there so you can close it next time? Of course, you'll need to use a variable that doesn't lose scope, i.e. a member variable rather than a local variable. If the last form you opened is still assigned to a member variable then you simply call `Close` on it.

Answer (score 0):

**1. First You create a MDIParent, a Main Form, a module code**

**2. Write code in module**

```
Module MainModule
    Public Forms1 As New List(Of frmMain)()

    Public Sub New1Form()
        Dim form2a = New frmMain
        Forms1.Add(form2a)
        Forms1.Item(Forms1.Count - 1).Text = "Form" & Forms1.Count - 1
        Forms1.Item(Forms1.Count - 1).Show()

    End Sub

    Public Sub NewForm()

        Dim form2a = New frmMain
        Forms1.Add(form2a)

        Dim form2b = New frmMain
        Forms1.Add(form2b)

        Forms1.Item(Forms1.Count - 1).Text = "Form" & Forms1.Count - 1
        Forms1.Item(Forms1.Count - 1).Show()
        Forms1.Item(Forms1.Count - 2).Text = "Form" & Forms1.Count - 2
        Forms1.Item(Forms1.Count - 2).Show()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CloseOldForm()
        If (Forms1.Count - 3) >= 0 Then
            Forms1.Item(Forms1.Count - 3).Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

**3. Write code in MDIParent1**

```
 Private Sub NewToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripButton.Click
        MainModule.New1Form()
    End Sub
```

**4. Write code in Main Form**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MainModule.NewForm()
        If (MainModule.Forms1.Count - 3) >= 0 Then
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
```

**5. Download source code**

https://www.tummosoftware.com/p/how-to-close-existing-running-program.html